# new installation appears to have got stuck

Tags: system-installation, 13.10

I'm installing Ubuntu 13.10 on a new out-of-the-box PC that was preinstalled with FreeDOS, and it's been on stage nine of the install guide for seven hours now, titled "Ubuntu One". Yet, it's opened an account for me as it sent me a confirmation email, but there appears to be no activity as the drive light is no longer flashing (it did for about 30 minutes at the start).

What should I do?

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. You have a problem installing 13.10 or ubuntu one? Please explain better and include any error messages that appear. Also, if possible , add some screenshots too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start the installation from scratch and skip the ubuntu one part for now...